# Ball bouncing problem, rounding error or algorithm error?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

On codewar there is bouncing problem said this :

"""
A child is playing with a ball on the nth floor of a tall building. The height of this floor, h, is known.

He drops the ball out of the window. The ball bounces (for example), to two-thirds of its height (a bounce of 0.66).

His mother looks out of a window 1.5 meters from the ground.

How many times will the mother see the ball pass in front of her window (including when it's falling and bouncing?

Three conditions must be met for a valid experiment:
Float parameter "h" in meters must be greater than 0
Float parameter "bounce" must be greater than 0 and less than 1
Float parameter "window" must be less than h.
If all three conditions above are fulfilled, return a positive integer, otherwise return -1.

Note:
The ball can only be seen if the height of the rebounding ball is strictly greater than the window parameter.

Example:

- h = 3, bounce = 0.66, window = 1.5, result is 3
- h = 3, bounce = 1, window = 1.5, result is -1
  """

Problem is not hard, solved in logarithmic time by:

```
    def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
        if  h > 0 and window < h and bounce > 0 and bounce <1:
            ct=1
            while bounce*h > window:
                ct += 2
                h *= bounce
            return ct
        else:
            return -1
```

My first impulse is to solve the problem in constant time like this:

```
    def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
        import math
        return 2*int(math.log(window/h,bounce))+1 if h > 0 and window < h and bounce > 0 and bounce <1 else -1
```

Not working because 19 times passed tests and 3 times NOT.  Error: "3 should equal 1", 2 times; "Exit code", 1 time.  I thought it was rounding problem, but no solution still.  Hope someone helps!

Comment: You don't need all these tags. `algorithm` and `math` are enough. Remove the others, or maybe replace them with `python` because the problem may be language specific. Also, if first code is the proper solution then find the input that yields different outputs, and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is little tricky and i found it out from test input.

While calculating you are assuming that if ball will bounce till window, mother will be able to see. i thought that too. but after looking at first test case(h=2,bounce=0.5,window=1,ans=1), i understood that ball need to be just higher than window for mother to see. so added 0.001.
[image: solution]

```
def bouncing_ball(h, bounce, window):
    if h <= 0 or bounce <= 0 or bounce >= 1 or window >= h:
        return -1
    return int(math.log((window+0.001)/h, bounce)) * 2 + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
    if not (h > 0 and (bounce > 0 and bounce < 1) and window < h):
        return -1
    else:
        return 1 if h < window else 2 + bouncingBall((h * bounce), bounce, window)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could explain why this works while OPs solution doesn't.

Comment: You will have recursion RecursionError on large test numbers